# How to partition a mirrored database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a couple of mirrored databases and would like to partition them to span over various less expensive disks. Can a mirrored database be partitioned ?

Answer (score 0):

A Mirror Database in Sql serve will be in a restoring state. You cannot do any Read or Write operations directly against the database itself.

The only thing that can get you access to a Mirror database in sql server Mirroring Sessions is a SNAPSHOT of a Mirror. Which is read-only you cannot make any (Write)changes to the snapshot.

A Simple answer to your question will be, No you cannot Partition a Mirrored Database at all.

Answer (score 0):

Logical layout of the principal and mirror must be the same. If the source database is partitioned, you can move filegroups to less expensive disks when initializing mirror from backup.